# What tags should we use to distinguish gender from sexual behaviour?

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-synonyms

We currently have two questions tagged [sex](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sex) that talk about behaviours that are possibly sexually motivated and three questions tagged [gender-differentiation](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/gender-differentiation).

My first instinct when seeing the tag [sex](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sex) was that it is about gender differentiation, and I personally find [gender-differentiation](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/gender-differentiation) a bit unwieldy and not necessarily the one I would search for when looking for questions in this regard.

I would probably tag a question about sexual behaviour with [sexuality](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sexuality) and [behavior](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/behavior) and one about gender differentiation with [sex](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sex) or [gender](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/gender) but your mileage may vary, so I wanted to get some community input.

Note that [gender-differentiation](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/gender-differentiation) at the moment at least has a tag wiki excerpt, whereas [sex](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sex) has not. So we should at least provide one for the latter in case we decide to keep them as is.

Answer (score 4):

I think the [sexuality](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sexuality) tag has been deleted because I just searched the [list of tags](https://pets.stackexchange.com/tags) and didn't see it.

Now to the [sex](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sex) and [gender-differentiation](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/gender-differentiation), I think the [sex](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sex) should be changed to **sexual behaviour**. Looking at the questions using the tag, they are more on sexual behaviour. The [gender-differentiation](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/gender-differentiation) tag should remain.

> ...and one about gender differentiation with [sex](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sex) or [gender](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/gender)

Once a new user comes to the site and types in gender in the tag, gender-differentiation will be suggested and even if the user doesn't find the tag and posts the question like that, The question will be edited to add the tag and the user will be notified.

Comment: I think that is a great way to differentiate between the two! :)

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, I was basically proposing [tag:sexuality] instead of [tag:sexual-behavior], I just formatted it as a tag to keep the look, so it never existed up to now. But [tag:sexual-behavior] is probably less ambiguous.

Answer (score 4):

I like [gender](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/gender) for all questions about gender.  I don't think questions about [gender-differentiation](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/gender-differentiation) will be different enough to warrant their own tag.  If you are asking about gender or asking how to determine the gender of an animal, the questions are similar enough that they should share a tag.

As for [sex](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sex), it is ambiguous, given the double meaning of the word.  I'd support renaming it to [sexuality](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sexuality).

Comment: Gender is a social construct of humans. I don't think it makes sense to even talk of animals having "gender" except by analogy.

Comment: @Wooble there is a biological difference between names and females, regardless of the species.  So gender might be a social construct, it provides an alternative term to avoid problems with sex being both a noun and verb.

Answer (score 2):

A [breeding](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/breeding) is useful, as it would cover all aspects of the reproductive cycle, [mating](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mating), [birthing](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/birthing), [whelping](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/whelping) [nursing](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/nursing) and [weaning](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/weaning) under the synonym   [breeding](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/breeding)

I  think [sexual-behaviour](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sexual-behaviour) and [sexuality](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sexuality) is covered by the the [behavior](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/behavior) tag. Sexual behavior is a little different from breeding, as in many users may ask questions, for example, about dogs mounting visitors.

I would suggest keeping any activities about sexual behavior that do not relate to [breeding](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/breeding) under behavior. I think a sexuality tag is unnecessary, it would come under behavior or psychology (and we haven't gone there yet on the site).

I believe a [sex](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sex) would relate to and be under the synonym [gender](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/gender), not sexual activities and this can be made clear in the tag wiki.

Comment: Very good point. We don't single out any other form of behaviour, so why this one.

Comment: @ThomasH there is a chat room, I'd like you to look at and make owner if you like the kennel http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/11052/the-kennel

Answer (score -1):

[procreation](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/procreation) or [breeding](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/breeding) ?

Comment: I would say gender and either breeding or mating

Comment: if yo make it one or the other, it would be easier to vote on, unless you're suggesting both